# Clever memory overview of c++ container usage when destroying

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, containers

I'm looking into my code as I have a slight increase in memory usage (reported by Windows) over time. I have added the debug-features from VS2012 to test for memory leaks, and I found none.

So, I'm looking into if any of my containers (vector,deque,etc.) are increasing unchecked.

Now, I'm currently writing manual checks for each container, but I'd rather do something clever and learn new stuff in the process. However, I don't know quite how to start.

What I'm looking for is an automated way to change my container allocations to include information like file and line position of allocation, and display this when the destructor is called. This would allow me to see if any have increased to a disproportionate size.

I'd prefer this is not done transparently for my code, sort of like the "new" modification to check for memory leaks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Henrik

Comment: The operating system will not unmap memory pages from your processes unless it needs to. That will make it seem like your memory is continually growing, and like you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: there's an element of truth there but I think it's missing the big picture...  most apps will quickly reach a "high water mark" for memory usage, after which pages will be freed up and reused roughly as often as they're re-allocated, with any steady growth genuinely of some concern - indicative of either a leak or some growing resource demand (e.g. an in-memory logging stream, a vector of events that never gets cleared).  That's separate from the question of what's genuinely in RAM and what's swapped out, which is where your observation fits in.

Comment: @Henrik: there's no support in the C++ Standard for intercepting container resizing of Standard containers with standard template parameters... you could instantiate with your own allocator or substitute your own type - but it'd involve quite a bit of change to client code or some very nasty `#define`s - take your pick.

Comment: @Tony: This was what I was dreading. My manual implementation of checks of the container sizes has not come up with any problem yet. I'm hoping that Joachim is right, but I fear that would be too easy. Thanks for the comments so far!

Comment: @Henrik: sound tricky... one thought is that sometimes it can help to limit the type of processing being undertaken during a run of the process - e.g. only feed it one type of request per run - you might find the growth in memory consumption is specific to processing for a single or subset of messages.  Another idea: put some memory logging or pauses in your process shut down, so you can get an idea whether there's a sudden drop in memory usage as some scope exits vs. static destructors run; either way, may be able to "binary chop" towards the problem.

Comment: @Tony: Sending only piecewise data is not easy in this case, if I opt out on any of the input this would prevent the process from completing. I.e. I combine many data sources to a single output and all the trimming/deallocation happens through this process.

Comment: You can replace the built-in `operator new` and `operator delete` functions with something which does some tracking.  Getting a stack trace is can't be done portably, and is generally non-trivial as well. (G++ has a built-in function, `backtrace`, to do it, but I'm not aware of anything similar with other programs.)  And of course, the backtrace information will typically be in hex, so you'll need a map to exploit it.

Comment: @James: Thank you for the comment. VS2012 has something similar built in with a slight modification, which allows tracking of allocation point etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know, what your vector is doing exactly, my hint may be too simple. But if you are using a C++11 compiler that supports *shrink_to_fit*

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/

perhaps it may help to call this function from time to time.

Comment: Hmm, I did not test for the "capacity". However, I mostly use the deque container. Will that have a tendency to "grow"?